# Tomee. Sending mails with attachment

Tags: email, tomcat, jakarta-mail, apache-tomee

I have a web application running on Tomee 1.7.1 Web Profile

When I send a simple mail from code using apache email lib, received email has no attachment.
The same code executed without Tomee works fine.

Here is the code:

```
HtmlEmail email = new HtmlEmail();
email.setHostName("localhost");
email.setSmtpPort(25);
email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("test", "test"));
email.addTo("test@test.test");
email.setFrom("test@test.test");
email.setSubject("Test");
email.setContent("Html content", "text/html");
MimeMultipart mimeMultipart = new MimeMultipart();
BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
messageBodyPart.setText("This is message body");
mimeMultipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
email.setContent(mimeMultipart);
EmailAttachment mailAttachment = new EmailAttachment();
mailAttachment.setName("Attachment");
mailAttachment.setDisposition(EmailAttachment.ATTACHMENT);
mailAttachment.setPath(pdfFile.getAbsolutePath());
email.attach(mailAttachment);
email.send();
```

Use resources gives the same results

```
@Resource(name = "mail/Test")
private Session mailSession;
```

*MultiPartEmail* gives the same result, a email without attachment

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with remove apache mail implementation from project dependencies, 
and switch to java mail api